# Vectorized conditional column

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

Say I had a data frame like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['v'] = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
df['w'] = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]

df['x'] = (df.v + df.w)+10
df['y'] = (df.v + df.w)+5

df['z'] = ...
```

I need a new column, `df.z`, to equal `df.x if df.v = 1` and `df.y if df.w = 1`

Of course, I could use `df.apply` here:

```
def non_vector(row):
    
    if row['v'] == 1: return row['x']
    if row['w'] == 1: return row['y'] 

df['z'] = df.apply(non_vector, axis=1)

print df

   v  w   x  y   z
0  0  1  11  6   6
1  0  1  11  6   6
2  0  1  11  6   6
3  0  1  11  6   6
4  0  1  11  6   6
5  1  0  11  6  11
6  1  0  11  6  11
7  1  0  11  6  11
8  1  0  11  6  11
```

But the issue seems straight forward enough for a vectorized method, as this is actually painfully slow.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You have [tag:python-2.7] tagged what are the pandas/numpy versions?

Comment: @Henry Ecker, pandas 0.24.2, and numpy 1.14.1

Comment: You might want to include that in your question body so people don't have to read the comments to find it. The available methods in both modules has grown and changed rather significantly since 2019.

Comment: Why not df[‘v’]*df[‘x’]+df[‘w’]*df[‘y’]?

Comment: if `v` and `w` are always the boolean opposite of each other then you can use `numpy.where` https://numpy.org/doc/1.14/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: @Mithridates the Great , excellent, kicking myself. Thanks.

Comment: @Henry Ecker, noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do this:

```
df['z'] = np.where(df['v']==1, df['x'],np.where(df['v']==0,df['y'], np.nan))
```

If `df.v` only takes the values 0 and 1, then

```
df['z'] = np.where(df['v']==1, df['x'],df['y'])
```

is enough. In both case you'd get:

```
v  w   x  y     z
0  0  1  11  6   6.0
1  0  1  11  6   6.0
2  0  1  11  6   6.0
3  0  1  11  6   6.0
4  0  1  11  6   6.0
5  1  0  11  6  11.0
6  1  0  11  6  11.0
7  1  0  11  6  11.0
8  1  0  11  6  11.0
```

Comment: I went with `df['z'] = df[‘v’]*df[‘x’]+df[‘w’]*df[‘y’]`, but this will come in handy.